# Apache Hive: How to obtain the runtime metrics of the hive queries executed from the JDBC as well as CLI?

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive

I am trying to get the runtime metrics of hive after executing the hive queries. Are there any API's to obtain these metrics. Please suggest.

The whole intention behind asking this question is to gather metrics for different mapreduce jobs spawned at each stage and the amount of memory and cpu being used for each stage.

> Hadoop Distribution: MapR (5.1)
>   Hive Version: 1.2.0 (Hive Server 2)

Comment: *"metrics of Hive"* -- what kind of "Hive"? the legacy fat-client `hive`, the thin client `beeline`, the HiveServer2 server? And what kind of metrics? Generic info about the Java process, info about the data processed in client or in HS2, info about the distributed MapReduce jobs spawned by the Hive DML queries, info about Metastore access by DML and DDL queries, info about locks set in ZooKeeper?

Comment: Wild guess since your question is so vague: if you are using JDBC, you can retrieve the raw Hive logs using methods specific to class `HiveStatement` (since Hive 0.14, and provided that HS2 configuration enables log retrieval) >> http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hive/hive-jdbc/0.14.0/org/apache/hive/jdbc/HiveStatement.java under `getQueryLog()` and `hasMoreLogs()`

Comment: And with a **lot** of parsing of these raw Hive logs, you will get the YARN job IDs that will allow you to query a REST API to get some stats about these jobs. Good luck.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter The whole intention behind asking this question is to gather metrics for different mapreduce jobs spawned at each stage and the amount of memory and cpu being used for each stage. I am using hive server 2.

Comment: Then update your question, with as much information as you can -- e.g. which distro, which version? On premises or in a public Cloud? Can you rely on Cloudera Manager API, or Ambari API, or *<name your Cloud product>* API?